# Routing within a NavBar in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my Profile component I have a NavBar that is supposed to have 2 child components. They do not render and I cant seem to find out why.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/Onthefly' render={() => (
          this.state.authed ? (<Redirect to='/Profile/' />
      ) : (
        <Onthefly/>
      )
        )} />
      <Route authed={this.state.authed} path="/Profile" render={() => (
          this.state.authed === false ? (<Redirect to='/Onthefly/' />
      ) : (
        <Profile/>
      )              ^// this checks if authorized go here
        )} />     //below is for the navbar in the profile component
      <Route authed={this.state.authed} path='/Profile' component={Profile} >
        <Route authed={this.state.authed} path='/Profile/Hoststand' component={Hoststand} />
        <Route authed={this.state.authed} path='/Profile/Bar' component={Bar} />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Below is my profile component that has the React-Burger-Menu Component and nested are the NavLinks

```
<Menu isOpen={ true } noOverlay customCrossIcon={ false }>

   <NavLink exact to="/Profile" className="menu-item">Home</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/Profile/Hoststand" className="menu-item">Host</NavLink>
   <NavLink to="/Profile/Bar" className="menu-item">Bar</NavLink>

</Menu>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not render appropriately"? Clarify please

Comment: when I click on the Navlink it shows the filepath in the URL but does not render the component

Comment: Try moving the Navbar routes inside the Profile component

Comment: Do you mean replacing the NavLink, or adding a Browser Router,Switch, and those NavBar routes below the Menu Component?

Comment: just tried it and still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use hash router with react-router-dom. I had some issues figuring this out too, and that was the only way I got it to work